# Error while formatting the date variables in sas

Tags: format, sas

I am getting an error when i try to do format for a date variable.

This is how my date variable values look-like "**26-Dec-58**"

"**The format $DATE was not found or could not be loaded**"

The reason for the error is that my date value is stored as a char variable in the data set so its not accepting the format of a numeric variable when i am formatting the variable.

So i want to convert my date (**which is a character**) variable into a numeric variable without introducing a new variable.

I tried **datepart** and **substring** options but still getting error.

I am still at the learning stage in sas so any code to clear the error is appreciated  i know the concept but coding i tried with all i know but still no luck.

Current code:

```
data Practice.Sales; 
    set Practice.Sales; 
    Birthdate = '26-Dec-58'; 
    Purchase_Dt = '15-Sep-04'; 
    t_num_date = input(Birthdate, ddmmyy8.); 
    t_num_date1 = input(Purchase_Dt, ddmmyy8.); 
    drop Birthdate Purchase_Dt; 
    format Birth_date ddmmyy8. PurchaseDt ddmmyy8. Price DOLLAR10.2; 
    rename t_num_date = Birthdate; 
    rename t_num_date1 = Purchase_Dt; 
run;
```

Comment: It begs the question - if you're hard-coding your dates, why not just define them as dates in the first place? `Birthdate = '26Dec1958'd; format Birthdate date9.;`

Comment: Anyway, these statements are not generating the mentioned error. What is there that you did not show us yet?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to change an existing variable in a SAS dataset directly from character to numeric. However, you can create a new numeric variable, drop the original character variable, then rename the new one:

```
data example;
    mydate = '26-Dec-58';
    t_num_date  = input(mydate, date9.);
    drop mydate;
    format t_num_date date9.;
    rename t_num_date = mydate;
    output;
run;
```

N.B. you have to apply the format to the temporary variable before it gets renamed. Attempting to apply a numeric format after renaming it results in an error, as the format statement is processed before the rest of the data step runs, and at that point the original character variable hasn't been dropped yet.

Comment: data Practice.Sales;
 set Practice.Sales;
  Birthdate = '26-Dec-58';
  Purchase_Dt = '15-Sep-04';
  t_num_date  = input(Birthdate, ddmmyy8.);
  t_num_date1  = input(Purchase_Dt, ddmmyy8.);
  drop Birthdate Purchase_Dt;
  format Birth_date ddmmyy8. PurchaseDt ddmmyy8. Price DOLLAR10.2;
  rename t_num_date = Birthdate; 
  rename t_num_date1 = Purchase_Dt;
  
 run;                                                    This is my code. This is not working just getting new variables at last added to the old variable with all data points as blank

Comment: As I mentioned above, you have to apply formats to the temporary variables before renaming them. Also, `ddmmyy8.` won't work here - you need to use `date9.`.

Comment: @Wasim You should edit your question instead of post code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me but still the newly created variables are coming at the last how to change that

```
  data Practice.Sales;
  set Practice.Sales;
    Birth_date=datepart(input(Birthdate,anydtdtm19.));
    PurchaseDt = datepart(input(Purchase_Dt,anydtdtm19.));
        format Birth_date PurchaseDt ddmmyy8. Price DOLLAR10.2;
        drop Birthdate Purchase_Dt;
    run;
```

Comment: Rename your old variables in the set statement and then drop them at the end.

Comment: Given your question, where it states the dates look like 26-Dec-58 it doesn't make sense to use datetime input as there is no time part. Are you sure that's giving you correct values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the rename at set statement and then drop them at the end.

```
 data Practice.Sales;
  set Practice.Sales 
   *rename old variables;
  (rename=(birthdate=birth_date purchase_dt=purchasedt));

  *use renamed variables in code;
  Birthdate=datepart(input(Birth_date,anydtdtm19.));
  Purchase_Dt = datepart(input(PurchaseDt,anydtdtm19.));

  format Birthdate Purchase_Dt date9. Price DOLLAR10.2;

  drop Birth_date PurchaseDt;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables in a SAS dataset appear in the order they were created.
If you really want to determine the order of the variables yourself, then you should create them before your  `set` statement. Further, I suppose you prefer NOT changing the name of the variables, while still changing their type. Therefore we have to rename the existing variables while reading them.

```
  data Practice.Sales;
    format Birthdate Purchase_Dt ddmmyy8. Price DOLLAR10.2;

    set Practice.Sales (rename =(Birthdate=oldBirth Purchase_Dt = oldPurchase));

    Birthdate=datepart(input(oldBirth,anydtdtm19.));
    Purchase_Dt = datepart(input(oldPurchase,anydtdtm19.));

    drop Birthdate Purchase_Dt;
  run;
```